# How to set Azure Webapp Websocket output buffer/frame size?

Tags: azure, websocket, iis-10

We're sending rather large chunks of data over websockets from an Azure Web App. It all works fine, but for some reason, the outgoing buffer size is 4096 bytes, which gives a lot of overhead for large data transmissions.

On a local developer machine this IIS/.Net buffer seems to be 16384 (or possible 16383 cause i'm getting the stream in one frame with 1 byte, and the next frame 16383 and on it goes). The reading buffer in the client in 65536 for reach frame.

All code is written in .NET so the sending side is simply creating a large ArraySegment and sending it with the ClientWebSocket.SendAsync which is much to high up the chain to actually decide how it's sent.

My question is, is it possible to change the size of the frames/buffers on the Azure Web App?

Clearly it's possible to change it on either OS or IIS level (http.sys?), since our Windows 10 dev machines have a different send buffer, but I really can't find where and how.